# Como permitir que una función se ejecute si no esta en ejecución actualmente?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función, la cual quiero que solo pueda ser ejecutada una vez que el intervalo establecido haya acabado:

```
function EarnMoney(i) {
    var x=TimeGen[i]-1;
    setInterval(function(){if (x>=0){Countdown(x, i); x--}}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){money += ReveGen[i] * LvlGen[i];}, TimeGen[i]*1000);
}
```

he intentado establecer una variable `isRunning=true` o `isRunning=false`, y luego permitir a través de un *if* ejecutar la función, así:

```
function EarnMoney(i) {
var isRunning=false;
if(isRunning=false){
isRunning=true;
var x=TimeGen[i]-1;
setInterval(function(){if (x>=0){Countdown(x, i); x--}}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){money += ReveGen[i] * LvlGen[i];}, TimeGen[i]*1000);
isRunning=false;
}
    }
```

sin embargo, esto no funcionó. Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias.-

Comment: Qué tan seguido se ejecuta la función EarnMoney? Varias veces por segundo o una cada X segundos?

Comment: Deberías meter EarnMoney al intervalo, no el intervalo al EarnMoney.